# Select query return one matching record

Tags: php, mysql

hello everyone its my first question here kindly guide me i am receiving id's in a variable it may be 2,3,4 on behalf of these id's i am fetching data from database when i run query directly in the databse it work fine when i use in file it returns just first matching record all other left

`$resid` in this varaibale i receive varaibles

```
$query_responsibilities_RS = "SELECT * FROM responsibility  WHERE resID IN ($resIDs)";
```

this is the query i am trying

```
$respons_RS = mysql_query($query_respons_RS, $timespace) or die(mysql_error());                                                     
$row_respons_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($respons_RS);
$total_respons_RS = mysql_num_rows($respons_RS);

$rescID = $row_respons_RS["rescID"]; here i need records but it returns one record i want to use this $rescID in second query 

$query_rescategories_RS = "SELECT *  FROM responsibility_category WHERE rescID IN ($rescID)";
$rescategories_RS = mysql_query($query_rescategories_RS, $timespace) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rescategories_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($rescategories_RS);
$total_rescategories_RS = mysql_num_rows($rescategories_RS);

<?php do{ 
          echo ("<h4>".addcslashes($row_rescategories_RS["rescName"],"\"")."</h4>");
        } while ($row_rescategories_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($rescategories_RS)); ?>
```

i use loop but i am getting only one record but i have more than one record

Comment: What is the loop you are trying? You'll want to do something along the lines of `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($respons_RS)) { echo $row['rescID']; }`

Comment: Although you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` - look into MySQLi and PDO. `mysql_*` has been deprecated for a while now and shouldn't be used

Comment: Can you echo _$rescID_? What value it contains?

Comment: place the echo AFTER the while loop

Comment: `$query_respons_RS` should be `$query_responsibilities_RS`

Answer (score 1):

you should loop it 
try the following code

```
while($row_respons_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($respons_RS)) {
 echo $row_respons_RS['rescID'];  //here you will get records 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty to use :

```
do{
$rescID[] = $row_respons_RS["rescID"];
}while ($row_respons_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($respons_RS));
```

and then:

```
$query_rescategories_RS = "SELECT *  FROM responsibility_category WHERE rescID IN (" . implode(",",$rescID) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line 
`$row_rescategories_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($rescategories_RS);`

from

```
$query_rescategories_RS = "SELECT *  FROM responsibility_category WHERE rescID IN ($rescID)";
$rescategories_RS = mysql_query($query_rescategories_RS, $timespace) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rescategories_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($rescategories_RS);
$total_rescategories_RS = mysql_num_rows($rescategories_RS);
```

it should only be use in while loop.

here

```
<?php do{ 
          echo ("<h4>".addcslashes($row_rescategories_RS["rescName"],"\"")."</h4>");
        } while ($row_rescategories_RS = mysql_fetch_assoc($rescategories_RS)); ?>
```